# Are php security patches and python security patches backported into Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04, 22.04?

Tags: updates, python, php, backport

PHP 7.4 will be EOL on 28 Nov 2022. Will Ubuntu backport php security patches be backported into Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04, 22.04?

The latest version of python available in the official Ubuntu 18.04 repository is 3.6 which was EOS Dec 2021. Highest CVE for Python 3.6. is 9.8 .  Example: CVE-2021-3177. Is Ubuntu backporting python security patches into Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a question about vulnerabilities, the first thing we should do is look at that CVE in the [Ubuntu CVE Tracker](https://ubuntu.com/security/cves).

And here's the result for CVE-2021-3177:

[image]

You can clearly see that patches for that particular CVE have been been applied to seven different releases of Python2 and Python3 in four different releases of Ubuntu.

The tracker will also show you specific package versions for each release, so you can confirm that your system is patched.

Specifically: You asked about Python 3.6 in Ubuntu 18.04. The tracker shows that this CVE was patched in version 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.4. The changelog for that particlar version shows that it was uploaded on 26 Jan 2021, a mere seven days after the CVE was recorded.

So, YES, the Ubuntu Security Team patches older packages in supported releases of Ubuntu.

Comment: Note that "ESM' releases require enrollment in Ubuntu Advantage of those systems to get extended security maintenance updates for those releases.  18.04 and 20.04 still receive regular security updates to the standard -security updates pocket.